# Android how to open Deezer from URI

Tags: java, android, android-intent, deezer

I want to open the Deezer Android Application from URI using Android Intent.

My code is:

```
try {
        uri = "deezer://track/"+track_id;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        uri = "http://www.deezer.com/track/"+track_id;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

However, the URI "deezer://track/track_id is never detected by Deezer and doesn't work.

Anybody knows the correct URI syntax for that ?

(I use the same code for Spotify and it works with the URI: spotify:track:track_id)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to use the `deezer://` scheme, you can use the following uri :

```
  uri = "deezer://www.deezer.com/track/"+track_id;
```

**Edit :**

You can also use some query parameters to add behavior to your link, for instance the following uri : `deezer://www.deezer.com/album/10596327?autoplay=true&start_index=13` will open the deezer app on the album's page immediately and will start playing with the 14th track (0 based index).

Comment: @XGouchet thank you! Could you please tell me if there is a way to pass an album's uri to Deezer, and start playing it automatically? I tried to start Deezer by intents with MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH (also with Intent.ACTION_VIEW) and some album's uri, like deezer://www.deezer.com/album/81931. Deezer showed the album's page, but didn't start playing

Comment: Hi @XGouchet :) Is there a way to do something like that for artists too? I mean automatically start playing. I tried to use autoplay parameter deezer://www.deezer.com/artist/290?autoplay=true , but it didn't work in this case. Neither deezer://www.deezer.com/artist/290/top?autoplay=true worked for me. Or maybe it is possible to get a link to the playlist that contains the list of top tracks of a particular artist?

Comment: @XGouchet where can we find documentation about this? This is the only place I've found this information so far. Where can I find more?

Comment: @kessir there used to be a PDF documentation on those deeplinks. I'm gonna forward the team responsible to update the online documentation.

Comment: @XGouchet any news on how to get further documentation? Those links still work, but don't appear to be documented anywhere, which is strange.

Comment: @IanS well I don't know anything about those URLs format, as I don't work at Deezer anymore. You might want to ask [DeezerDevs] on twitter :/

Comment: Merci ! I thought of it but I worried that they might retire these URLs if they are brought to their attention ;)